# select2 I don't want to get data out of json

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, jquery-select2

My script won't load any data in the Select2. I made data from laravel controller with response JSON data, this result json

```
  "results": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "code": "11",
      "name": "jackson",
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "code": "12",
      "name": "michael,

    },
```

this my script code

```
$('.name_user').select2({
      width: "100%",
      placeholder: "Search...",
        ajax: {
          url: "{{route('name_user')}}",
          processResults: function(data) {
            return {
              results: $.map(data, function(obj) {
                return {
                  id: obj.id,
                  name: obj.name
                };
              })
            };
          },
          cache: true
        }

      });
```

How do I get data from route name_user?

Comment: you want only the list of names to be return is that what you mean?

Comment: yes, online name and id

Comment: you can easily achieve that, in your controller. You could use pluck or `->select(['name', 'id'])` instead of selecting all columns.